# Is it possible to limit no. of returned value in array_keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Further to the user manual of `array_keys` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), it will return all values or pass a parameter to filter the required values in `array_keys`.

However, if I would like to get first 10 record sets in `array_keys`, can I do that? If no, what is the alternatives.

Example:

```
$results = array_keys($products);
```

Comment: cut the resultant array, slice or splice

Comment: you can use - array_slice

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help and this answer solved the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$results = array_slice(array_keys($products),0,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use array_slice to get the desired result

```
$keys = array_slice($products, 0, 10);
```

replace 10 with the desired number of elements